# Reducing lag during blob detection of real-time, binary b/w webcam feed using cvblobslib and opencv(c++)

Tags: c++, opencv, cvblobslib

I'm building a skin-detection algorithm that takes constant, real-time feed with a webcam, converts it to a binary image (based on the skin color of the person's face), and filters out the noise by only <strike>showing</strike> focusing on the largest blobs (using CvBlobsLib). The output of my code, however, shows a lot of lag, and I'm not sure what to change to make it faster.

Here's (the important part of) my code:

```
Mat frame;
IplImage ipl, *res = new IplImage;
CBlobResult blobs;
CBlob *currentBlob;
cvNamedWindow("output");

for(;;){

    cap >> frame; //get a new frame from camera
    cvtColor(frame, lab, CV_BGR2Lab);//frame now in L*a*b*
    inRange(lab, BW_MIN, BW_MAX, bw);//frame now only shows "skin values"...BW_MIN/BW_MAX determined earlier
    ipl = bw; //IplImage header

    blobs = CBlobResult(&ipl, NULL, 0);
    blobs.Filter(blobs, B_EXCLUDE, CBlobGetArea(), B_LESS, 10000);
    res = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&ipl), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    cvMerge(&ipl, &ipl, &ipl, NULL, res);
    cvShowImage("output", res);
    if(waitKey(5) >= 0) break;

    }

cvDestroyWindow("output");
```

I convert Mat to IplImage because CvBlobsLib only works with the IplImage type.

Does anyone see a way that I could make this faster? I've just recently heard other blob detection libraries do a better job with real-time video, but I'd be interested to see if there's something I'm simply overlooking in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decrease the resolution of the camera capture using set [method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set)

`set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH , double width)`

and

`set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT , double height)`

If your default capture resolution is too high, this can increase the detection speed considerably.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Still not at real-time feedback, but much, much better.